# Determining which tabpage has opened

Tags: c#, click, tabpage, contextmenustrip

I'm trying to get the `tabpage` that was clicked by right button of mouse,in another words the `tabpage` that opened the `contextmenustrip`.

There's a `toolstripmenuitem` called Close which I used to close the tab that was clicked on.

I used this code :

```
public partial class USBrowser : Form

    {
        private Point lastpoint;
    }


private void closeTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < browserTabControl.TabCount; i++)
    {
        Rectangle rec = browserTabControl.GetTabRect(i);
        if (rec.Contains(this.PointToClient(lastpoint)))
           closeTab(i);//this function closes the tab at specific index                
    }
}

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            lastpoint = Cursor.Position;

    }
```

I also added(when adding the `tabpage`) :

```
    browserTabControl.TabPages.Insert(browserTabControl.TabCount - 1,WebPage);
    browserTabControl.SelectTab(WebPage);
    browserTabControl.SelectedTab.MouseClick += SelectedTab_MouseClick;

    void SelectedTab_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            lastpoint = Cursor.Position;
    }
```

The problem is that the lastpoint is always (0,0)  !!
Why ?
Any other suggested idea is welcomed 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these event handlers will actually run.  Not the form's OnMouseClick() method since you are not actually right-clicking the form.  And not the tab page's MouseClick event handler since you gave the TabControl a context menu.  So lastpoint being empty is the expected outcome.

It is not clear how you want this context menu to work.  If you use it by right-clicking the tab page then it is simple, just destroy the selected page:

```
    private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Dispose();
    }
```

If you activate it by right-clicking a tab, one that isn't selected, then it gets more complicated.  You have to memorize which tab was clicked on, do so by using the context menu's Opening event:

```
    private TabPage RightClickedTab;

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        RightClickedTab = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
        var pos = tabControl1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        for (int tab = 0; tab < tabControl1.TabCount; ++tab) {
            if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(tab).Contains(pos)) {
                RightClickedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tab];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (RightClickedTab != null) RightClickedTab.Dispose();
    }
```